# Module not found: Can't resolve 'net' when i importing twilio shows,Nextjs error

Tags: javascript, next.js, twilio, mern

Console

[image: 1]

I started to learn Next.js. When i import Twilio, it shows errors "fs not found,net not found"

```
./node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js:15:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'net'

    Import trace for requested module:
    ./node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/index.js
    ./node_modules/twilio/lib/base/RequestClient.js
    ./node_modules/twilio/lib/index.js
    ./components/Login/ForgotPassword.jsx
    ./components/Login/Login.js
    ./pages/login/index.js
    
    https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

I know Next.js runs code on both the client and server side, but this looks like you are trying to use the Twilio library in the client. The Twilio library is not built to be used in the client side and this is expected behaviour.

**If you try to make calls to the Twilio API from the front end, you will expose your Account SID and Auth Token, which could be taken by a malicious user and used to abuse your account.**

Instead, you should make calls to the Twilio API on the server side and make requests from your front end to your own server to do so.

Here's an example of [sending an SMS from React with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-an-sms-react-twilio) (though not with Next.js) that I wrote and here's a blog post that looks like it shows what you should do, by [creating an API route in Next.js to send an SMS with Twilio](https://thetechhulk.com/heres-how-you-can-send-messages-to-your-phone-with-nextjs-and-twilio). Whatever you are hoping to do with the API, those posts should give you an idea how to approach it.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 5, **Webpack** doesn't include polyfilles for node libraries.

Adding the following **Webpack** config in your **next.config.js** should do the trick:

```
const nextConfig = {
  ...
  webpack: config => {
    config.resolve.fallback = { ...config.resolve.fallback, net: false, os: false };
    return config;
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running code on the client. Or at least nextjs is thinking that you are running code on the client. Try to follow the stack trace and see how you are calling the code that is importing `net`.